# Enzyme wrapper doesn't show the new state after setting new props

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a jest code below in the same test.js:

describe("Settings Component - Batch Settings", () =>{

```
const props = {
    type: 'Batch Config',
    version: '1100',
    handleSaveZipFile: jest.fn()}

const wrapper = shallow(<Settings store={store} {...props}/>).dive();

test('Test Batch Settings Dom', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('BrowseAeiConfigFile').exists()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

});

describe("Settings Component - USB Provisioning", () =>{

```
const props = {
    type: 'USB',
    version: '1100',
    handleSaveZipFile: jest.fn()}

const wrapper = shallow(<Settings store={store} {...props}/>).dive();

console.log('---USB wrapperUSB------state---------------------', wrapper.state('selectedCheckbox'))
```

});

question: I was expecting that the second "describe" has a new state, but console output indicates that it is the first "describe" state. But if I comment out the first "describe", then the second "describe" will be the proper state, could someone know and tell me why? a lot of thanks!

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. But a reasonable suspicion is that this is because of `store`. If you don't want to preserve the state then don't reuse the state.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer.  I really appriciate it!  And you are right , I following your tips and finally I found that it is the store cause the problem.